# trying to read all the file in s3 content sorted by time using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get all the files content sorted by the time the file was uploaded, I have this code:

```
keys = []

kwargs = {'Bucket': 'my_bucket'}
while True:
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
    for obj in resp['Contents']:
        keys.append(obj['Key'])

    try:
        kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
    except KeyError:
        break
```

but it returns me only the keys...

if I'm doing:

```
keys.append(obj)
```

it returns me a dict but I can't figure out how to get the files content in a normal run-time... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

usually when you try to go through all the files on a S3 bucket you will encounter performance problems. 
I would suggest to add S3 events and inform the "listener" about the new files through an queue (SQS).
Thus as soon as you copy a new file a new message is sent to the SQS (since we have created a S3 event), then the client will consume the SQS queue and do whatever is appropriate with the pending files. This is much faster than traversing the whole S3 bucket over and over.
Here is a link for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Another solution would be to analyse your S3 bucket with the help of Amazon Athena. https://aws.amazon.com/athena/

I hope that you will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `LastModified` to sort by time. Something like:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

all_objects = []
kwargs = {'Bucket': 'my-bucket'}

while True:

    # List objects in bucket
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)

    # Create an array of (Modified Date, Key) tuples
    for object in response['Contents']:
        all_objects.append((object['LastModified'], object['Key']))

    try:
        # Next page
        kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = response['NextContinuationToken']
    except KeyError:
        break

# Sort by LastModified
sorted_keys = [object[1] for object in sorted(all_objects)]
print (sorted_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `boto3 paginator` and iterate through each page and access the obj `Key` & `LastModified`

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=REGION)
    pages = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_it = pages.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET)
    files = {}
    for page in page_it:
        for content in page['Contents']
            files[content['Key']] = content['LastModified']

    sorted(files, key=lambda k: k[1])
```